# How can we describe an RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) with a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, rpn

I'm making an evaluator for an RPN given by input and I tried to write down a regular expression in order to check if the input is correct. I know that I can't fully know if it is correct by the match but which could be the most precise one? I tried with this one but it doesn't work.

```
private String regex = "\\d+\\s+(\\d+|[\\+-*/])*";
```

Comment: You're better off writing a proper parser for anything non-trivial here - see stack-based examples in the wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Comment: I've already done the evaluator and it works fine but I was trying to write a regex for the expression as an exercise for my exam

Comment: Math expressions are inherently irregular, which means it's not correct to think you can write a regular expression that could match any math expression. You can only do that with a very specific final set of possible expressions, but since you don't say anything about that, you meant to match all expressions. And that, as I said, is not possible.

Comment: I know that it can't describe every expression so I was trying to figure out the best regex possible

Answer (score 0):

```java
private String regex="(\\\d+\\\s+)+\\\d+(\\\s+(\\\\+|\\\\-|\\\\*|\\\\/))+";
```

This may be fine for a necessary but not sufficient condition; in fact,
if you put for example more operators than operands this regex anyway says that is right.

```java
private String rpnExpr="2 3 4 * /";
```